# Get response time of web client web-flux

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

Just want to know if there is any way to get the response time of web client of spring web-flux?

Answer (score 8):

you also have the possibility to use `elapsed()` for this kind of thing

```
webClient.get().uri("/bla").retrieve()
     .bodyToMono(String.class)
     .elapsed()  // map the stream's time into our streams data
     .doOnNext(tuple -> log.info("Milliseconds for retrieving {}", tuple.getT1()))
     .map(Tuple2::getT2) // after outputting the measurement, return the data only
```

Note, that `elapsed()` elapses the whole reactive stream, so if you're doing something before the webClient... part, you should put an elapsed() before that - this resets the timer.

Answer (score 4):

With Spring Boot you have built-in metrics for that. See [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12228).

If you want to implement your custom stopwatch, you could do something like this:

```
Mono<String> resultMono = Mono.subscriberContext()
        .flatMap(context -> webClient.get()
                .uri("/foo")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .doOnNext(ignored -> log.info("Execution duration is {} ms",
                        System.currentTimeMillis() - context.<Long>get("stopWatch"))))
        .subscriberContext(context -> context.put("stopWatch",
                System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

Comment: I assume this only works for one item, what about flux?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the metrics from HttpClient:

```
HttpClient.create(...
.....
.metrics(true, CustomMetricsRecorder::new);
```

and:

```
public class CustomMetricsRecorder implements HttpClientMetricsRecorder {

    @Override
    public void recordDataReceivedTime(SocketAddress remoteAddress, String uri, String method, String status, Duration time) {
      System.out.println("Client metric: " + durationToString(time) + " - DataReceivedTime - " + uri + " " + method.toUpperCase());
    }
    @Override
    public void recordDataSentTime(SocketAddress remoteAddress, String uri, String method, Duration time) {
      System.out.println("Client metric: " + durationToString(time) + " - DataSentTime - " + uri + " " + method.toUpperCase());
    }
    @Override
    public void recordResponseTime(SocketAddress remoteAddress, String uri, String method, String status, Duration time) {
      System.out.println("Client metric: " + durationToString(time) + " - total req+resp - " + uri + " " + method.toUpperCase());
    }
    @Override
    public void recordDataReceived(SocketAddress remoteAddress, String uri, long bytes) {

    }
    @Override
    public void recordDataSent(SocketAddress remoteAddress, String uri, long bytes) {

    }
    @Override
    public void incrementErrorsCount(SocketAddress remoteAddress, String uri) {

    }
    @Override
    public void recordDataReceived(SocketAddress remoteAddress, long bytes) {

    }
    @Override
    public void recordDataSent(SocketAddress remoteAddress, long bytes) {

    }
    @Override
    public void incrementErrorsCount(SocketAddress remoteAddress) {

    }
    @Override
    public void recordTlsHandshakeTime(SocketAddress remoteAddress, Duration time, String status) {
      System.out.println("Client metric: " + durationToString(time) + " - TlsHandshakeTime - " + remoteAddress);
    }
    @Override
    public void recordConnectTime(SocketAddress remoteAddress, Duration time, String status) {
      System.out.println("Client metric: " + durationToString(time) + " - ConnectTime - " + remoteAddress);
    }
    @Override
    public void recordResolveAddressTime(SocketAddress remoteAddress, Duration time, String status) {
      System.out.println("Client metric: " + durationToString(time) + " - ResolveAddressTime - " + remoteAddress);
    }
  }
```

will print:

```
Client metric: 00:00.09 - ResolveAddressTime - xxxx.com:443
Client metric: 00:00.69 - ConnectTime - xxxx.com/52.210.218.144:443
Client metric: 00:00.87 - TlsHandshakeTime - xxxx/52.210.218.144:443
Client metric: 00:00.01 - DataSentTime - /xx/xx/v1 POST
Client metric: 00:00.14 - DataReceivedTime - /xx/xx/v1 POST
Client metric: 00:00.122 - total req+resp - /xx/xx/v1 POST
```